# extracting substring according to given start and end points

Tags: php, mysql, string, substr

I am trying to extract substring from string gettting from mysql database using `substr` function:

```
substr($mystring,$startpoint,$endpoint);
```

here start and end point can be any number.

But I am not getting gesired result. Ptart point works but something is wrong with end point.

What is reason?

**Edit**

when I am pasin start ans end point like 15 and 50, start point is working fine so resultant string is starting from 15th char of main string .  but end point is not working it's giving me meand end char in resultant string is not 50th of main string.

Comment: To ask the reason, first you got to show the problem? Where is full code. And what are the error you receive?

Comment: you should provide some more lines of code for us so that we are able to determine what values `$startpoing` and `$endpoint` have...

Comment: please correct your english and add a code sample

Comment: If you read the manual and check the third parameter, you will know. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. ayart and end point can be any number. say I want to get substring from 15 to 50 from a large string.

Comment: Only Christofer Eliasson is guy who got what am I asking. you guy s not tried to understand what I am asking. Every thing is clear in my question,You just wait for new commer to downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subtract `$endpoint-$startpoint` and pass it as third parameter to get desired output.

like below:

```
substr($mystring,$startpoint,($endpoint-$startpoint));
```

Comment: Thanks. .. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have mixed up endpoint with length. The third parameter of [`substring()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the length of the string - thus number of characters from the start point. Not the index of the last character.

```
<?php 
$str = "A short string";
echo substr($str, 2, 2); // Prints sh
echo substr($str, 2, 4); // Prints shor
?>
```

If you want to specify an end point, you can calculate the length by subtracting the startpoint from your enpoint:

```
<?php
$startpoint = 2;
$endpoint = 5;
$str = "A short string";
echo substr($str, $startpoint, ($endpoint - $startpoint)); // Prints sho
?>
```

Comment: Yes got your point. But what to do if want to get substring between given start and end point.

Comment: @nikhil You could calculate the length. See my updated example.

Comment: :Thank you too. Helped me lot

Answer (score 1):

third parameter is for specifying length from start point.

But you want to get string till value in third parameter so both are different.

Try below it will work.

```
substr($string,$startpoint,($endpoint-$startpoint));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

**length**, not endpoint.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 0):

string substr (string $string, int $start [, int $length])

that means:

```
<?php 
$text = "foobar text";
$startpoint = 0;
$endpoint = $startpoint + strlen($text);
echo substr($text, $startpoint, $endpoint);
?>
```